# Why do parent elements sometimes not cover the children's dimensions?

Tags: html, css, background, css-position, background-color

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/lolcatBH/pen/OJbgLyd

I have the following html:

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="click">SHOW POPUP</div>
  <div class="popup">
    <h1>Korean language</h1>
    <button class ="close">X</button>
    <div class="desc">Korean (North Korean: 조선말/朝鮮말, chosŏnmal; South Korean: 한국어/韓國語, hangugeo) is an East Asian language spoken by about 77 million people.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.popup {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  transform: scale(0);
  padding: 20px;
}

#page .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

#page.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.click {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1, desc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
const click = document.querySelector('.click');
const x = document.querySelector('.close');
const page = document.querySelector('#page');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

const showPopup = () => {
  page.classList.toggle('active');
  popup.classList.add('active');
}

const hidePopup = () => {
  page.classList.toggle('active');
  popup.classList.remove('active');
}

click.addEventListener('click', showPopup);
x.addEventListener('click', hidePopup);
```

At first, what I tried to do is instead of creating a separate `overlay div`, I was going to put a background color on the `#page` element. However, in effect, the background only applies to the `button` element (`.click`). I don't actually understand why in this case, since the `background-color` doesn't seem to affect the `.popup` element.

Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT10d.jpg

So my question is, why does the `#page` element not cover all of its children's width and height? In this case, I thought it would have cover the whole page. I've also tried putting `width: 100vw` and `height:100vh` but it in turn only applied the dimensions to the button.

Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwgbA.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that most of your elements have `position` set to `absolute` or `fixed`, which makes them completely (`fixed`) or partly (`absolute`) independent from their parent, i.e. there is no space of its own reserved for them, therefore they typically overlap other elements.

So the parent doesn't span or cover them, but only those elements which don't have a set `position` or which have `position: relative` or `static`.

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 related questions: 1) So I've taken off all the `absolute` and `fixed` positions on the children elements and I set the parent width and height to be `100%`. My question is why are the parent's dimensions now not extending over the whole page but fit to its children's? I'd have thought it'd expand to its parent's element (which is the page's body). Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/kbo7qSw

Comment: 2) There is some awkward white spacing around the `#page` element. Why is this happening?

Comment: Add `html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }`, which should fix both to some extent. Percentage height needs a set height in the direct parent, so if there are any other elements layered between `body` and your element, also these need `height: 100%;